# Is it possible to configure where core files are stored on Solaris?

Tags: solaris

I believe that, by default, core files on Solaris (and on most if not all other UNIX-like systems) are saved to the directory where the offending binary was invoked.

Is there a way to reconfigure this so that core files are generated to a specific location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command that you're looking for is `coreadm`

There are various patterns that you can use to set the file name based on the process/user etc. - see the man page for details.
For example, to put core files under /var/core/core.[executable name].[process id]:

```
coreadm -g /var/core/core.%f.%p
```

Answer (score 1):

see "man dumpadm" and "man coreadm"